# Webscrapping, Selenium worked, but it started to send empty result. No code change. Debug shows result

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So I have the following code to import a price from a website.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
value=[]

url = "https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=col14-3#T=S&O={%22reg%22:%22-1%22,%22iconly%22:0}"
driver.get(url)
wait_time = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="_idStoreResultListSection"]/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[5]')))
path = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="_idStoreResultListSection"]/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[5]').text
price = path.split('\n')[0].split(" ")[1].strip()

print(price)
```

It worked. It printed the price. All of a sudden it no longer works. I haven't changed the code. So, if I run a debug test and I look by

```
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='//*[@id="_idStoreResultListSection"]/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[5]')
```

If I expand the list ([you can see on the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro4wV.png)), you can see that the result appears under text. So, why doesn't it get it ?

Weird detail. On the debugging if I search immediately by

```
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='//*[@id="_idStoreResultListSection"]/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[5]').text
```

It's empty. If I expand like on the image, and then search it again, it appears the text.

Few notes: I'm calling url as a variable, because my goal is to be able to loop the url to get more than 1 result and append the results to a list.

I hope I was clear enough. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what went wrong in your code, but instead of dealing with fragile, interminable xpath values, what you could do instead is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=col14-3#T=S&O={%22rpp%22:%22500%22,%22iconly%22:0}'

browser.get(url)
dfs = pd.read_html(str(browser.page_source))
df = dfs[0]
new_header = df.iloc[17]
df = df[18:]
df.columns = new_header
desired_df = df[['Description', 'Condition (Qty)', 'Seller', 'Price']]
desired_df
```

This will return a dataframe with 385 rows × 4 columns, like below (containing name, seller, price - which I imagine you wanted to obtain):

```
17  Description Condition (Qty) Seller  Price
18  Monster Scientist, Series 14 (Complete Set wit...   Used (1)(Incomplete)    Steve's Spare Bricks (670) United Kingdom Mi... US $1.67 (GBP 1.40)
19  Monster Scientist, Series 14 (Complete Set wit...   New (2)(Incomplete) 182 Auto Club (8) United Kingdom Min Buy: None  US $1.79 (GBP 1.50)
20  Monster Scientist, Series 14 (Complete Set wit...   Used (1)    Edisbricks (26) Finland Min Buy: None   US $2.03 (EUR 2.00)
21  Monster Scientist, Series 14 (Complete Set wit...   Used (1)    Random set shop (61) Ireland Min Buy: None  US $2.03 (EUR 2.00)
22  Monster Scientist, Series 14 (Complete Set wit...   Used (1)    The Brick Store NL (127) Netherlands Min Buy... US $2.03 (EUR 2.00)
... ... ... ... ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually that's not my goal. My goal is to retrieve for various figures just one value (instead of multiple values for 1 fig), which would be the one I consider to be the fair value (which is the 9th cheaper price for european union, hence the xpath being constant for every url), create a file with the values and update on a database. Although, I do believe that I'll be able to adapt your code to my objectives.

Comment: The result is a dataframe containing all prices/names/quantitites/sellers from page, so it would be straighforward to do any calculations you need on prices.